# Can't open php file on localhost

Tags: php

I'm a beginner in PHP language, and I tried to display a simple file named info.php with the following content :

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

So I ran Firefox, to the address http://localhost/~jules/info.php (jules is my Ubuntu login) but it does not work. It tells me :

Not Found

The requested URL /~jules/info.php was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

The file info.php is placed in ~/www, and I checked the DocumentRoot is well set to ~/www. I really don't understand my mistake.
Could you help me please ? 
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried just http://localhost/info.php

Comment: this isn't a php problem. you script isn't being executed at all, because the webserver can't find it. that means it's a webserver configuration problem

Comment: Does `http://localhost/~jules/` work? You'd need to enable a module for that, and the files are expected to be in `~/public_html` usually.
Have you set the `DocumentRoot` to `/home/jules/www/`? Because `~/www` point to the`httpd` homedir.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't enabled the option in Apache that lets you access files in user directories.

Comment: When I go to localhost/~jules/, I get the same error message. I also modified the DocumentRoot to ~/www.

Comment: this isn't a programming question, it's a hardware/software issue. Voted to close as such.

Answer (score 3):

How are your Apache skills? If you are still using the defaults then Ubuntu will be loading it's config from:
     /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

This specifies that the DocumentRoot is:
     /var/www/html/

Put your php file in this folder and try navigating to http://localhost/info.php to see if your script runs.

There are modules and ways of getting Apache to look in your users folder, but it could be that you don't require that if you just want to try out some PHP.

Here is a link to [basic Apache on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html) configuration.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89931/discussion-on-answer-by-steve-e-cant-open-php-file-on-localhost).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must have PHP running on your computer.
The following link: http://localhost/~jules/info.php tries to load a file(info.php) located not in www root. It is located at `/home/jules` (your home folder)

Try to put your info.php file in this directory: `/var/www` the default public_html directory of apache servers, then navigate to localhost/info.php

If you want to mantein the tilda-URL, have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html

Comment: If you don't have PHP running, you'll get the raw source of the PHP file as the result, you won't get "Not found".

Comment: you will get a not found error, just because in /home/jules there is no file, or there is no permission to read it. No userdir enabled

Comment: I moved the file in /var/www and went to localhost/info.php in my browser but I get a blank page without anything.

Comment: go to `/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`, then set `<Directory "/var/www">`

Comment: I have tried it, but I don't have a /etc/apach2/conf folder. I have /etc/apache2/conf-available and /etc/apache2/conf-enabled

Comment: go in the conf-enabled and check it

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the httpd.conf file in the conf-enabled folder